# Cast create error while as not

Tags: c#, casting

I have little peace of code:

```
private static void Casting<T>(T obj)
{
    String str = (String)obj; //Error
    str = obj as String;
}
```

Line `String str = (String)obj` returns me compile-time error

> "Error    CS0030  Cannot convert type 'T' to 'string'"

Lets say, I agree with the error. 
But why second line do not same behavior?
So my question is - why "as" do not generate the error, while casting do?

Comment: String str = (String)(object)obj;

Comment: What is this code supposed to be doing exactly? Not everything will convert to a string

Answer (score 2):

When using `as`, if a cast is not possible, `null` is returned instead of throwing an exception like a 'normal' cast would do.

See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx

Comment: i am not talking about runtime. I am talking about compile time

Comment: @zzfima - Compile time is the exact same answer, because `as` can handle it, there is no need to invent warnings/errors about something the developer probably already knows

Answer (score 1):

By using `(String)obj` you say to compiler "Hey I am absolutely sure that this type can be converted to a `string` - just do it!" where in `as` operator - it's when you allow compiler to do it's job and say 'please try to convert it for me if it's possible'...

Something like this :D